# JFrame not showing JPanel and other widgets in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So here's my code, I'm still a newbie in GUI for Java (just started this week). From what I understand, you create a JFrame, to which you add JPanels to, then on those panels you can add widgets like JRadioButton etc.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Binary extends JFrame{
private JLabel header;
private JTextField userInput1;
private JButton doIt;
private JButton clear;
private JRadioButton binary, decimal;
private JLabel number2;
private JFrame frame1;
private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel panel2;

public Binary(){

    super("Number Converter");
    frame1 = new JFrame("Binary to Decimal Converter");
    frame1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setSize(250,500);
    frame1.setVisible(true);

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setSize(250, 450);
    frame1.add(panel1);

    header = new JLabel("1- Select the mode: ");
    panel1.add(header);

    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setSize(250, 25);
    panel2.setOpaque(true);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame1.add(panel2);


    ButtonGroup choices= new ButtonGroup();
    binary = new JRadioButton("Binary to Decimal"); // add the first radiobutton binary to decimal
    choices.add(binary);
    decimal = new JRadioButton("Decimal to Binary"); // add the second radiobutton decimal to binary
    choices.add(decimal);
    this.add(binary); // adds both to the program
    this.add(decimal);

    userInput1 = new JTextField(20); // Adds a blank text field for user input
    frame1.add(userInput1);

    number2 = new JLabel("2- Enter some words then click Do It:"); 
    frame1.add(number2);

    doIt = new JButton("Do It"); // left button do it
    frame1.add(doIt);

    clear = new JButton("Clear"); // right button clear
    frame1.add(clear);
}

}
```

For my code here, when I run it, there's only a frame with `Binary to Decimal Converter` and nothing else, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As already stated in the answer, plus, the use of `setVisible(...)` before adding all components to the __Top Level Container__, before it actually establishes it's size, are the culprits, it seems :-) Try to remove all `component.setSize (...)` calls, simply add them to the `JFrame` and once done, simply call `JFrame.pack()` and then set it to visible using `JFrame.setVisible ( true )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making two copies of a `JFrame`, one you are showing on the screen and one you are adding your components to.

```
public class Binary extends JFrame {
    //...    
    private JFrame frame1;
    //...
    public Binary() {

        super("Number Converter");
        frame1 = new JFrame("Binary to Decimal Converter");
```

Instead of extending from `JFrame`, simply create an instance and use it instead...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Binary {

    private JLabel header;
    private JTextField userInput1;
    private JButton doIt;
    private JButton clear;
    private JRadioButton binary, decimal;
    private JLabel number2;
    private JFrame frame1;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;

    public Binary() {

        frame1 = new JFrame("Binary to Decimal Converter");
        frame1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setSize(250, 450);
        frame1.add(panel1);

        header = new JLabel("1- Select the mode: ");
        panel1.add(header);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setSize(250, 25);
        panel2.setOpaque(true);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame1.add(panel2);

        ButtonGroup choices = new ButtonGroup();
        binary = new JRadioButton("Binary to Decimal"); // add the first radiobutton binary to decimal
        choices.add(binary);
        decimal = new JRadioButton("Decimal to Binary"); // add the second radiobutton decimal to binary
        choices.add(decimal);
        frame1.add(binary); // adds both to the program
        frame1.add(decimal);

        userInput1 = new JTextField(20); // Adds a blank text field for user input
        frame1.add(userInput1);

        number2 = new JLabel("2- Enter some words then click Do It:");
        frame1.add(number2);

        doIt = new JButton("Do It"); // left button do it
        frame1.add(doIt);

        clear = new JButton("Clear"); // right button clear
        frame1.add(clear);

        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Still comes out as a blank window.. :/

Comment: Try with the new changes

Comment: it works! But how do I set the size now of the different panels? Because it's all coming out the same way even if i have `setSize` or no, I feel like `pack()` is the culprit but how could I change it so that it resembles what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You can call `setSize` on the frame, but `pack` is generally safer.

Comment: thanks so much! I'm also wondering, why isn't my panel2 stacking onto my panel1? That's what I'm initially trying to do to have different block of colors in one frame.

Comment: Because you're adding `panel1` and `panel2` to the same container.  If you want then layout out in a more vertical manner, you could use a `GridLayout` instead of a `FlowLayout`